# Leaflet change layer color when click on marker

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to change the fill color of the State in the usa map when the marker on that state is clicked.  I have been able to get the state color to change when clicking on the state but cannot get the color to change when clicking on the marker.
The map is here: https://www.thekeithcorp.com/map-properties/

I am trying to use a click event listener, the flyto is working as its supposed to but not the color change.

This is my code:

```
shelter1.addEventListener("click", function (e){
map.flyTo([35.7,-79.0], 7);
restyleLayer(name, layer);
});

  function getColor(name) {
    color: 'red'
   }

  function restyleLayer(name, layer) {
layer.feature.properties.name = 'North Carolina';
var myFillColor = getColor(name);
layer.setStyle(myFillColor);
   }
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Where do the values for `name` and `layer` come from in your call to `restyleLayer(name, layer);` ?

Comment: Make sure that the change of color is part of the properties within the FeatureCollection of Layer Feature.